Sending USDT or other tokens over TON network using React and @tonconnect/ui-react
I’ve been developing a React app that connects to a TON wallet and allows sending tokens over the TON network. By default, it sends TON to the receiver’s wallet, but I want to modify it to send USDT instead. I couldn’t find a clear guide in the @tonconnect/ui-react docs. Could someone please help me with this?
import React, { useCallback, useState } from 'react';
import ReactJson from 'react-json-view';
import './style.scss';
import { SendTransactionRequest, useTonConnectUI, useTonWallet } from "@tonconnect/ui-react";


const tonToNanoTON = (amountInTON: number): string => {
    const nanoTON = amountInTON * 1_000_000_000;
    return nanoTON.toString();
}
type TxFormProps = {
    tonno: string; // Define the type of tonno
  };
  
const defaultTx: SendTransactionRequest = {
    // The transaction is valid for 10 minutes from now, in unix epoch seconds.
    validUntil: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 600,
    messages: [

        {
            // The receiver's address.
            address: 'my address here',
            amount: tonToNanoTON(0.000005),// this sendsTON but i need to send USDT
            stateInit: 'te6cckEBBAEAOgACATQCAQAAART/APSkE/S88sgLAwBI0wHQ0wMBcbCRW+D6QDBwgBDIywVYzxYh+gLLagHPFsmAQPsAlxCarA==',
            payload: 'te6ccsEBAQEADAAMABQAAAAASGVsbG8hCaTc/g==',
        },


    ],
};


    export function TxForm({ tonno }: TxFormProps) {

    const [tx, setTx] = useState(defaultTx);
    const wallet = useTonWallet();
    const [tonConnectUi] = useTonConnectUI();

    const onChange = useCallback((value: object) => setTx((value as { updated_src: typeof defaultTx }).updated_src), []);
    const sendTx = () => {

        const d = tonConnectUi.sendTransaction(tx).then((res) => {
            console.log(res, "test");
    
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error("Transaction failed", error);
            // Optionally handle errors or show a message to the user
        });
        

    }
    return (
        <div className="send-tx-form">
            <h6>RECIEVER WALLET:-  --8MVY1W </h6>
            {wallet ? (
                <button onClick={() => sendTx()}>
                    Send transaction - {tonno} TON
                </button>
            ) : (
                <button onClick={() => tonConnectUi.openModal()}>Connect wallet to send the transaction</button>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}


You have to build the body payload of the transaction. This is in my project
const body = beginCell()
    .storeUint(0xf8a7ea5, 32) // op transfer
    .storeUint(0, 64) // queryId
    .storeCoins(toNano(depositAmount)) // deposit_amount
    .storeAddress(
      Address.parse("receiver address"),
    ) // receiver address
    .storeAddress(Address.parse("exceed fee receiver")) //response_adress - address nhận phí GD thừa
    .storeMaybeRef(null) // custom_payload
    .storeCoins(toNano("0.05")) // forward_ton_amount
    .storeMaybeRef(beginCell().storeStringTail("something").endCell()) // forward_payload_amount if receiver is a smart contract
    .endCell();

  const myTransaction: SendTransactionRequest = {
    validUntil: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 360,
    messages: [
      {
        address: jettonWalletAddress.toString(true, true, true), // Your USDT jetton wallet address
        amount: toNano(0.1).toString(), // feee
        payload: body.toBoc().toString("base64"), // payload with jetton transfer and comment body
      },
    ],
  };


hi... I was stuck for 15 days in this but cant get any infor.. can you comment complete script to send USDT using Mnemonics using js please. It will be very helpful
